# Unexpected behavior in R using lapply() with glm() and cv.glm()

Tags: r

I am trying to apply cross validation to a list of linear models and getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
library(MASS)
library(boot)
glm.fits = lapply(1:10,function(d) glm(nox~poly(dis,d),data=Boston))
cvs = lapply(1:10,function(i) cv.glm(Boston,glm.fits[[i]],K=10)$delta[1])
```

I get the error:

Error in poly(dis, d) : object 'd' not found

I then tried the following code:

```
library(MASS)
library(boot)
cvs=rep(0,10)
for (d in 1:10){
glmfit = glm(nox~poly(dis,d),data=Boston)
cvs[d] = cv.glm(Boston,glmfit,K=10)$delta[1]
}
```

and this worked.

Can anyone explain why my first attempt did not work, and suggest a fix?

Also, assuming a fix to the first attempt can be obtained, which way of writing code is better practice? (assume that I want a list of the various fits and that I would edit the latter code to preserve them)  To me, the first attempt is more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your first attempt to work, `cv.glm` (and maybe `glm`) would have to be written differently to take much more care about where evaluations are taking place.

The function `cv.glm` basically re-evaluates the model formula a bunch of times. It takes that model formula directly from the fitted `glm` object. So put yourself in R's shoes (as it were), and consider you're deep in the function `cv.glm` and you've been instructed to refit this model:

```
glm(formula = nox ~ poly(dis, d), data = Boston)
```

The fitted `glm` object has `Boston` in it, and `glm` knows to look first in `Boston` for variables, so it finds `nox` and `dis` easily. But where is `d`? It's not in `Boston`. It's not in the fitted `glm` object (and `glm` wouldn't know to look there anyway). In fact, it isn't *anywhere*. That `d` value existed only in the context of the `lapply` iterations and then disappeared.

In the second case, since `d` is currently an active variable in your `for` loop, after R fails to find `d` in the data frame `Boston`, it looks in the parent frame, in this case the global environment and finds your for loop index `d` and merrily keeps going.

If you need to use `glm` and `cv.glm` in this way I would just use the `for` loop; it might be possible to work around the evaluation issues, but it probably wouldn't be worth the time and hassle.